# How Can I Make /bin/sh point to /bin/bash?

Tags: bash, dash-shell

In Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` points to `/bin/dash` [by default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40411/why-does-bin-sh-point-to-bin-dash-and-not-bin-bash).

I want to use `/bin/bash` as my system-wide shell for `/bin/sh`. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As shown on [this Ubuntu wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh), you should run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

and select the option **not** to use `/bin/dash` as the default shell. Making the change this way will not only fix the symlink `/bin/sh`, but will also configure other parts of your system to behave correctly, such as making sure that `man sh` points to the bash manpage instead of the dash one.

Comment: Good to know. At the risk of hitting some mined terrain here: What would be a use-case for this?

Comment: It isn't terribly uncommon for certain software to require this. For example, building [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) requires `/bin/sh` to point to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: This one had me head scratchin' as VxWorks wrsdk for vscode threw error during a build because of this freaking dash prank.