# update-alternatives for sh reports bash is used, but I still get dash

Tags: bash, sh, update-alternatives, dash-shell

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10 from Ubuntu 17.10.

I have my box configured to use `bash` as the default shell rather than the default `dash`.  I've made this change with `sudo update-alternatives --config sh` which reports:

```
  Selection    Path            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /bin/dash        200       auto mode
* 1            /bin/bash        100       manual mode
  2            /bin/dash        200       manual mode
```

However, `/bin/sh` still points to `dash` rather than pointing to `bash`.

Actually, on previous versions of Ubuntu, I believe that used to point `/bin/sh -> /etc/alternatives/sh`.

It looks like the latest Ubuntu no longer allows the `alternatives` mechanism for `sh` or at least broke the alternatives during the upgrade.   I see from [How Can I Make /bin/sh point to /bin/bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064773/how-can-i-make-bin-sh-point-to-bin-bash) that it is now recommended to reconfigure dash instead.

Why doesn't `alternatives` work anymore? Where is this change documented?   I've been using alternatives with sh for at least three years in Ubuntu and I've never had it broken during an upgrade before.  There are many guides that suggest that such as: https://jwaghetti.blogspot.com/2015/09/changing-dash-to-bash.html

Comment: I don't think /bin/sh has ever been managed through alternatives. On LTS versions 14.04 through 18.04, running `sudo update-alternatives --config sh` outputs `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for sh`.

Comment: @wjandrea It was certainly managed by alternatives.   I've always had alternatives for sh available, probably because I've also installed bash.  See https://jwaghetti.blogspot.com/2015/09/changing-dash-to-bash.html

Comment: That blog is incorrect, you shouldn't use alternatives unless the packages installing the symlinks and binaries are doing that as well. It's probably for that reason that your system is now inconsistent with respect to that symlink.

Comment: For people voting to close as duplicate,  I've edited the question to specifically ask about why alternatives isn't working.  Just knowing that I could reconfigure dash doesn't answer that quesiton.  @FilipeBrandenburger could you add a little more explanation about that and put it in as an answer?    I think that mostly answers my question about why alternatives isn't working, or gets broken during updates.

Comment: It might be interesting and/or helpful to explain in what contexts / for what purpose you want Bash to be used rather than Dash. Voting to leave the question open as is though. Definitely well worth having a unique answer here

Comment: @Stephen OK, fair point. I removed my close vote.

Comment: Related: [`update-alternatives` vs `dpkg-reconfigure` - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/437849/117037)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Make /bin/sh point to /bin/bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064773/how-can-i-make-bin-sh-point-to-bin-bash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `update-alternatives` system *could* have been used to manage `/bin/sh`, but it would have had to be implemented that way in the Debian packages for bash and dash.

The packagers decided against it, instead using the current scheme involving `dpkg-configure` to manage `/bin/sh`. See [this excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/437926/281844) for details and rationale of that choice.

The [article you linked to](https://jwaghetti.blogspot.com/2015/09/changing-dash-to-bash.html) is recommending using `update-alternatives` on `/bin/sh`, setting that up manually. That is **terrible advice.** Because, in effect, you'll have two separate systems trying to manage the same symlink in different ways, and probably stepping on each other's toes. (Which is probably what caused your issue during an Ubuntu upgrade.)