# Mistakenly modified `/bin/sh'

Tags: scripts, sh

I had this script:

```
spd-say "Hello, don't forget the trash bin."
```

So it reminded me of what I supposed to do, and I moved it to `/usr/local/bin/` and the command `trash` pronounced the argument,then I set a *crontab job*, to make it remind me everyday what I wanted to do. But the *crontab* didn't work and I couldn't understand why(It does other jobs flawlessly).

Once I saw this message in my terminal:

```
You have new mail in /var/mail/root
```

at the end of which this line made me do a bad mistake:

```
/bin/sh: 1: trash: not found
```

I know that it was a silly thing to do but I did:

```
mv /usr/local/bin/trash /bin/sh
```

thinking that `sh` is a directory and I should move the script there in order to be executed.

Now, when I want to see a man page the system says:

> "Hello, don't forget the trash bin."

And the output of `cat sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
spd-say "Hello, don't forget the trash bin. "
```

Anyway, can I do anything or I have to reinstall my operating system?

Comment: I'm speculating, but cron jobs run with a very limited environment, including a $PATH with just a few directories. That might be why it works from the terminal, but not through cron. (In fact, when something works from a normal terminal but not through cron, that's the first thing I check.)

Comment: @ a CVn; I don't know what the problem is but when I replace *spd-say* by *echo* and set the crontab  job: trash > ~/Desktop/trash.txt**, it works & a file is created on my Desktop. I think I should ask about it in another question.

Comment: Yes, if you want to ask about that, please do ask it as a separate question.

Comment: *'Now, when I want to see a man page the system says: "Hello, don't forget the trash bin."'* To be fair, most `man` docs are rubbish (or difficult to understand)

Comment: @LogicalBranch I disagree; I love them;they're powerful, off-line guides.

Comment: @Coditoergosum I intended for my comment to be a pun *(trash bin/rubbish...)*. `man` docs can be quite useful but only if you're not a complete beginner (I speak from personal experience) which is why I wrote that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Ubuntu systems, `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to the `dash` shell by default:

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jul  7  2018 /bin/sh -> dash
```

So (assuming your terminal emulator uses the bash shell, and didn't get broken by your mistake) all you need to do is re-create the link:

```
sudo ln -sf dash /bin/sh
```

Comment: ***OP:*** `mv /usr/local/bin/trash /bin/sh`, ***`sh`***: You could not live with your own failure, where did that bring you? Back to me.

Comment: @LogicalBranch how do you only have 1 upvote for that masterpiece?

Comment: @vikarjramun it sounds like a masterpiece but i just dont quite get it...

Comment: @Nacht it's from Avengers: Endgame; a line from the villain, Thanos.

Comment: @Cullub Oooooh..... thanks... I'm pretty sure I get it now...

Answer (score 7):

No, you don't have to reinstall your system.  /bin/sh is only a softlink to your shell. `readlink -f /bin/sh /bin/bash` In my case bash. Move your script and make a softlink to your favorite shell.

Comment: /bin/sh should actually point to /bin/dash. If you want to change the system shell, use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash`, per [How Can I Make /bin/sh point to /bin/bash?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1064773/301745). Also note the system shell is not the default interactive shell.